# How can I programatically select a tableview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

when I create a custom UITableviewCell I set `cell.selected = YES` in the `UITableView` delegate method `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but it doesn't work.

However, when I call [tableView selectRowAtindexPath:] after [tableview reloadData], there is no problem.  I am confused

Here is some code source:

```
-(void)setModel:(GAInterestSetModel *)model
{
    _model = model;
    if (model.iconURL && model.iconURL.length > 1) {
        [iconView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:model.iconURL]];
    }
    if (model.title && model.title.length > 1) {
        titleLabel.text = model.title;
    }
    if (model.memberCounts) {
        membersLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"成员：%d",model.memberCounts];
    }
    self.selected = model.defaultChoosed;
}
```

instead method:

```
[modelsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        tempModel = (GAInterestSetModel *)obj;
        if (tempModel.defaultChoosed) {
            [rootTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Update your title to be more "Question like" as putting that much in a title doesn't help anyone

Comment: where are you calling `setModel:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection is not a property of the cell. Calling `.selected = YES` does absolutely nothing because the table doesn't know about the selection.

You have to use `[table selectRowAtIndexPath:...]` otherwise it won't work.

Another possibility is to ignore the default selection and implement your own selection mechanism.